# Fetching data from 3 tables using inner join

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am fetching into a table  from database table, i made a table (**files**)  which have attribute column like , id , name , process and action , in action  when user enter any action then action value  goes to another database table(**update_table**) and second table column are id , reason and update date, 
now when user does not enter data in update table 
then code is

```
if(isset($_GET['post_id']))
{
    $page_id=$_GET['post_id'];
    $query="SELECT files.id, files.file_name , files.recieved_by , files.processed_by , files.purpose, files.address , files.contact_no , files.date ,update_table.reason,update_table.update_date FROM files INNER JOIN update_table ON files.id=update_table.id WHERE files.id='$page_id'"; 
    $run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0)
    {
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);
        $id =$row['id'];
        $fname=$row['file_name'];
        $recieved=$row['recieved_by'];
        $processed=$row['processed_by'];
        $purpose=$row['purpose'];
        $address=$row['address'];
        $contact=$row['contact_no'];
        $status=$row['reason'];
   }
}
```

and in output, table should show row information without update table value 
and when user enter data in update table then input  should show update_table and file table column in one query . 
and when i am using query like this

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE files.id'$page_id' union SELECT files.id, files.file_name , files.recieved_by , files.processed_by , files.purpose, files.address , files.contact_no , files.date , update_table.reason,update_table.update_date FROM files INNER JOIN update_table ON files.id=update_table.id WHERE files.id='$page_id'
```

but out put is coming as 
The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns , help me please , i am struglling with this for 3 days

Comment: `UNION` use with same number of column from different table or same table in query

Comment: what is your problem

Comment: @Bhargav problem is when i am doing below query it is showing error , i wanted if there is no entry in update table ,still it should catch from file table and show only file table column ad when update table have entry then it should show both update_table and files table entry

Comment: use left join instead of inner join. it selects all the data from file table and its matching rows from update table.

Comment: @Rits left join is when wanted to select from left table and any other matching from second table and using this how can i perform above problem

Comment: Left join fetches all the rows from first table and matching from the another. if it not get matching rows it only returns first table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT files.id , files.file_name,files.recieved_by,files.processed_by ,files.purpose,files.address,files.contact_no,files.date , update_table.reason,update_table.update_date FROM files LEFT JOIN update_table ON files.id=update_table.id WHERE files.id='$page_id'
```

use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Comment: @Raj okay if there is any other problem just let me know

Comment: okay Sir , there is problem with search key pagination problem and when session should destroy

Comment: For the pagination you have to use  unset($SESSION['key']) after you want to unset the session

Comment: after you do a new search, you are overriding the $_SESSION['search'] with POST value arelady in your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158685/discussion-between-raj-and-vikash).